# What would an Elven ship on the straight road look like from an accompanying Mannish ship that follows the curvature?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

If two ships leave Mithlond besides each other, an Elvish one about to take the straight road to Aman, and one with a human crew accompanying the Elvish one in the same direction, what would the Elvish ship's path look like from the human crew's point of view? With Middle-earth curving away, would the humans see the Elvish ship start levitating and going up the sky as if it was flying? Would they see it slowly fading until it disappears, or disappearing at a certain distance from Middle-earth's coast? Or would the Mannish ship sail themselves (illicitly) the straight road or both ships wouldn't sail the straight road but follow the curvature because of the too-close Mannish ship?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on two quotes from *The Silmarillion*, we can suppose that *if*, hypothetically, there was nothing stopping the Elven ship from sailing the Straight Road that it would look like it was sailing along an invisible bridge as the Mannish ship fell away:

> **while the new world fell away, the old road and the path of the memory of the West still went on, as it were a mighty bridge invisible that passed through the air of breath and of flight** (which were bent now as the world was bent), and traversed Ilmen which flesh unaided cannot endure, until it came to Tol Eressëa, the Lonely Isle, and maybe even beyond, to Valinor

> had entered in upon the Straight Way and seen the face of the world sink below them
> <sub>The Silmarillion: Akallabêth</sub>

The air of breath and of flight is Vista, the lower part of the atmosphere that surrounded Arda, which the boats are quite clearly described as traversing. The description of the bridge to Tol Eressëa and the world sinking below suggest if the Straight Road could be found with a Mannish ship in tow, and only the Elven ship had sailed onto it, it would look like it was floating away.

There is, however, the possibility that the Mannish ship would've also sailed onto the Straight Road as was claimed in Númenorean traditions. Extending the second quote above shows us that some believed that Men, "by the grace of the Valar", had stumbled onto the Road and sailed to Tol Eressëa before then passing away:

> And tales and rumours arose along the shores of the sea concerning mariners and men forlorn upon the water who, by some fate or grace or favour of the Valar, had entered in upon the Straight Way and seen the face of the world sink below them, and so had come to the lamplit quays of Avallónë, or verily to the last beaches on the margin of Aman, and there had looked upon the White Mountain, dreadful and beautiful, before they died.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Comment: The quote probably means "as _if_ there was a mighty bridge".

Comment: That is another way of putting that line, yes

Comment: It certainly sounds as if Valinor is in space....

Comment: @Adamant - Tolkien has a recent quote (in *Nature of Middle-earth*) saying that Aman was not a satellite.

Comment: Of course, but the description sounds more like that than anything else.

Comment: @Adamant - Because at the time of these quotes it probably was that. The stuff in NoME is from a later phase in the legendarium.

Comment: Well, there is clearly something supernatural/magical about the Straight Road. Its *looking as if* one is traversing physical space, for someone who *is* allowed to find the Straight Road, doesn't necessarily mean that someone *not* allowed to find it can fly to Aman with a rocket. Aman after the Downfall is probably something like "Faerie", not exactly in our physical space.